# Ckeditor contentelement="false" working but it can be delete or Replace

Tags: replace, ckeditor, contenteditable

I need to block editing and deleting in some (CKEDITOR) elements. 
I am trying with the attribute of  `contenteditable='false'` 
but its allowing to delete and replace.

How can I dodge this issue?

Please review below content:

```
<Elems>
<Elem1>Editable Content</Elem1>
<Elem2>unchangable content</Elem2>
<Elem3>Editable Content</Elem3>
</Elems>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [CKEditor Widgets feature](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9764) that perfectly matches your requirements. It's under development and it'll be available in CKEditor 4.3.

---

Update: The [feature](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets) has been in the core for a while and it's stable. There's an official [guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1) about Widgets API.